# Filter image collection with a month range for each year in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have used the codes below to calculate the total annual for the image collection based on Calendar Year. Now I want to calculate the sum again using a water year, from 8/1/2018 to 8/31/2019 as one year for example.

How do I make my own annual range filter in Google Earth Engine?

```
> // Set start and end of time series

var startYear = 1981;

var endYear = 2019;

var regions = "municipio";

// Create a list of years by generating a sequence from start and end years 

var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);


// Generate annual summed image mosaics 

var annualPrecip = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (year) {
    var annual = chirps
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
        .sum();
    return annual
        .set('year', year)
        .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).format("YYYY_MM_dd"));
}));
```

Comment: Just change the second year to `ee.Number(year).add(1)` [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f104adda5d460ad5796341f803f652c4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create two dates from `ee.Date.fromYMD` that represent the start and end of the water year in your mapped function. Add vars for water year start/end month and day; year is determined from the `map`-provided `year`. Use the given `year` for the start date and add 1 to `year` for the end date.

```js
var startYear = 1981;
var endYear = 2019;
var regions = "municipio";
var startWaterMonth = 8;
var startWaterDay = 1;
var endWaterMonth = 8;
var endWaterDay = 31;

// Create a list of years by generating a sequence from start and end years 
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);

// Generate annual summed image mosaics 
var annualPrecip = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, startWaterMonth, startWaterDay);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1), endWaterMonth, endWaterDay);
    var annual = chirps
      .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
      .sum();
    return annual
      .set('year', year)
      .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).format("YYYY_MM_dd"));
}));
```

Comment: Make it server-side operation: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d441ab37d55f41da2e080bef7148ee9c

Comment: Thanks Kuik. I edited the script.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I have tried this, but it generates a water year for 1981, and low value for 2019. The output should not have 1981 since the data start from 1981...so it would start with 1982 (8/1/1981-8/31/1982). any idea why?

Comment: The year is being set by `ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)` so it is valid to have 1981 in your collection because the first year in the `years` list is 1981. If you want the composite year set to the later year in a water year, use: `ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1), 1, 1)`

Comment: Using this, my last year for the output has changed to 2020. Since the CHIRPS data are available from 1981/1/1 - present, how would I make the code only calculate my 1982 water year (1981/8/1-1982/8/31) etc? Currently, I am not sure which calculated value is for which year...

Comment: Since your water year crosses the new year your annual composite mean is based on images within two calendar years. You'll need to decide whether to label them with the early or late year. Or use some other unit, like the middle of the water year as milliseconds or decimal years since unix epoch. To prevent your time series extending into 2020, set the `endYear` to 2018, because the mapped function adds 1 to the given year in the `years` list to set the end date of the date range to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

Please include a link to a working script in your questions. It makes it easier to help you. You can do something like this:

```
var startYear = 1981;
var endYear = 2019;
var regions = "municipio";
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY')
var annualPercip = ee.ImageCollection(
  years.iterate(function (year, collection) {
    year = ee.Number(year)
    var percip = chirps
      .filterDate(
        ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1), 
        ee.Date.fromYMD(year.add(1), 1, 1)
      )
      .sum()
    return ee.ImageCollection(collection).merge(ee.ImageCollection([percip]))
      .set('year', year)
      .set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1).format("YYYY_MM_dd"));
  }, ee.ImageCollection([]))
)
print(annualPercip)
Map.addLayer(annualPercip.first(), {min: 600, max: 900}, 'First year')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f434c6c922b3730da2a5f155604508b3

Comment: It's best to avoid `iterate` if you can. First try using joins, then mapping over a list, then iterate. Some operations are truly iterative and depend on the previous result to produce current result, but this is often not the case for collection building.

Comment: Right - Justin's solution is definitely better